# Why is a piezoelectric material a capacitor?

Tags: capacitance, piezoelectric

I am reading about piezoelectric elements and I am not sure why a piezoelectric material is like a capacitor. So a mechanical stres on the material will displace the electric charge distribution creating a potential difference. But current cant flow through ? So why is it a capacitor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that is exactly the effect a capacitor gives: It causes current to flow in other parts of the circuit around it due to attraction/repulsion of charges on either side of it - but no current can actually flow through it.

- In essence, in the piezoelectric element you have an atomic structure of the unit cell which skews the charge distribution towards one side when it is mechanically "squeezed". See this nice illustration from [this source](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/piezoelectricity/):

[image]

- A capacitor on the other hand is "filled up" with charges when connected to a battery or other voltage source. Charges of opposite sign will place themselves on either of the capacitor's plates. Illustration from [this source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html):

[image]

The result in both of these is now that you have a positive net charge on one side and a negative net charge on the other, while there is no conducting material in-between through which charge can move. So, current can't flow through them, but they nevertheless are able to *drive* current as a voltage source because of their net voltage across their oppositely charged sides - much like a battery, albeit their voltages will vary very differently over time.